# Is there a formal way to define $\mathbf{R}(X^n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, definition

For example $\mathbf{C}$ or $\mathbf{R}[i]$ can be defined as $\mathbf{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$ but this is to "extend" $\mathbf{R}$.

Is there a "similar" way to define $\mathbf{R}(X^n)$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you possibly explain what $\mathbb{R}(X^{n})$ means to you in this context?

Comment: I'm not sure what $R(X^n)$ is but the ring of polynomials in multiple (possibly infinite) variables $R[\{X_i\}]$ is a free module over $R$. In particular if $M$ is any module over $R$ (I assume that $R(X^n)$ is a module over $R$) then $M$ is isomorphic to $R[\{X_i\}]/J$ for some submodule $J$. If $M$ is additionally finitely generated then the set of free variables $\{X_i\}$ can be chosen to be finite.

Comment: @Boots $R(X^n) = {P(X^n)/Q(X^n), P, Q \in R[X]}$

Comment: @freakish is it possible to explicitly say what J is in that particular case?

Comment: @Thomas So if I understand correctly $R(X^n)$ is a ring of all rational functions with nominator and denominator of the form $P(X^n)$ for some $P\in R[X]$.

Comment: So, $R(X)$, the ring of all rational functions can be expressed as $R[X,Y]/(XY-1)$. But I think that $R(X^n)$ for $n>1$ is infinitely generated over $R$. I'm not sure though. But if that's the case then you won't get a nice description of $J$.

Comment: @freakish No, the rational functions in one variable are not the same as Laurent polynomials in that variable. You need to invert much more than the variable to get all rational functions.